# Apache Spark (PySpark): sort parquet data globally and divide in equal size

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Is that possible to have parquet data sorted across all partitions and additionally divide the data in equal partitions (counting how much data I have and dividing into 64 or 128 to get equal files) in S3?

The reason behind having everything sorted and equally divided is having better compaction in S3 and reducing number of scans in Athena when querying data from S3.

What I tried is the following:

1. Doing repartition `df.orderBy(col1, col2).repartition(100).write('s3://')` - gives equal partitions however sort order is not kept due to shuffling 2 times (orderBy and repartition)
2. Doing orderBy and then coalesce `df.orderBy(col1, col2).coalesce(100).write('s3://')` - preserves the order but produces not equal partitions, also sometimes I need to increase number of partitions over spark.sql.shuffle.partitions and coalesce will not do that.
3. Doing orderBy and relying on spark.sql.shuffle partitions: `--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=100, df.orderBy(col1, col2).write('s3://')` - preserves the order but output files are not equally divided.

Ways to solve that:

1. I can do "secondary sort", like '`repartition(100).sortWithinPartitions(col1, col2)`' but this will not be a "global" sort
2. Go with option 3 and create a custom partitioner that would make sure that partitions are equal (but in PySpark having custom partitioner is a bit of a problem)
3. One more option that I could think about is partition by range, and then sortWithinPartitions. That should give the total sort, but its not easy to determine those ranges appropriately as data can come in different "flavor".

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here...

Comment: just wondering if df.repartition(100).orderBy would work?

Comment: No, it will repartition the data to 100 (you will have equal sizes) then orderBy will produce number of files equal to spark.sql.shuffle.partitions - at least this is what I've seen so far